# Don't want some part information in output

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Hi Guys I have the following code which search a folder and return any string containing the value down:

```
filter MultiSelect-String( [string[]]$Patterns ) {
  # Check the current item against all patterns.
  foreach( $Pattern in $Patterns ) {
    # If one of the patterns does not match, skip the item.
    $matched = @($_ | Select-String -Pattern $Pattern)
    if( -not $matched ) {
      return
    }
  }

  # If all patterns matched, pass the item through.
  $_
}

Get-ChildItem -recurse | MultiSelect-String 'report','Product1'
```

---

So if the code gets the file it displays it like that:

```
Directory: C:\Users\sarvesh.nundram\Desktop\PMI\RPD_Extract_XML\SQL_tobemigrated2\GROUP1

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        11/21/2013   1:07 PM     133279 Acapulco
```

What if I don't want these info:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        11/21/2013   1:07 PM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this?

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | 
        MultiSelect-String 'report','Product1' | 
           select fullname # or select -expa fullname
```

Comment: Hi, it does not returned the desired results but the code is good when I test it on other different files. it gives the results which I required.

Comment: @sar04x. Maybe the problem is with the files you tested! Glad to help.